# Spring MVC controller returning null modelAttribute when @Valid fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I've been scratching my head for a long time on this one.  I'm working on a web app that has over 20 controllers and i'm having this strange issue with only one of them.  No matter how long I compare with a working one i cannot seem to find any differences.  Basically, I am able to add an Interface entity no problem as long as it does not fail validation.  If i try to save say a completely empty object (or leave one of the required fields blank for example) I get this error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'intface' available as request attribute

Here is the relevant code :

View :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="intface" class="form-style-7">
            <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="name">Name: </label> </td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" id="name"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="type">Type: </label> </td>
                    <td><form:input path="type" id="type"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="type" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="ip">IP: </label> </td>
                    <td><form:input path="ip" id="ip"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="ip" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="port">Port: </label> </td>
                    <td><form:input path="port" id="port"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="port" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="test">Test: </label> </td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="test" id="test"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="test" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${edit}">
                                <input type="submit" value="Update Interface"/>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <input type="submit" value="Add Interface"/>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newInterface"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveInterface(@Valid Interface intface, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {
        return "interfaceDataAccess";
    }
    interfaceService.saveInterface(intface);
    return "redirect:/interfaces/list";
}
```

Entity :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/newInterface"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveInterface(@Valid Interface intface, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {
        return "interfaceDataAccess";
    }
    interfaceService.saveInterface(intface);
    return "redirect:/interfaces/list";
}
```

You will notice this @Unique annotation which is something i built.  Essentially it allows me to check if one of the values entered by the user already exists and that works just fine on my other entities.  I tried removing it completely and i still get this exception as soon as validation fails.  I literally have over 20 controllers that work the exact same way, line for line, and they work fine.  This completely baffles me and i'm sure it's something really stupid.  I can provide the MVC code for a working entity for comparison if needed.

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

Here is some working code for my heightUnit class:

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/newHeightUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newHeightUnit(ModelMap model) 
{
    HeightUnit heightUnit = new HeightUnit();
    model.addAttribute("heightUnit", heightUnit);
    model.addAttribute("edit", false);
    return "heightUnitDataAccess";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/newHeightUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveHeightUnit(@Valid HeightUnit heightUnit, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
    if (result.hasErrors()) 
    {
        return "heightUnitDataAccess";
    }
    heightUnitService.saveHeightUnit(heightUnit);
    return "redirect:/heightUnits/list";
}
```

View :

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="heightUnit" class="form-style-7">
            <form:input type="hidden" path="id" id="id"/>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <form:input path="name" id="name"/>
                    <span><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></span>
                </li>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${edit}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update Height Unit"/>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Height Unit"/>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </ul>
        </form:form>
```

Entity :

```
private int id;
private String name;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getId() 
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) 
{
    this.id = id;
}

@Size(min = 1, max = 15, message = "Name must be between 1 and 15 characters long")
@Unique(entityType = "heightUnit", field = "name", message = "The name needs to be unique!")
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 15)
public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{
    if (obj instanceof HeightUnit)
    {
        HeightUnit heightUnit = (HeightUnit)obj;
        if (id == heightUnit.getId())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() 
{
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 37 * hash + this.id;
    hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
    return hash;
}
```

This works perfectly and i'm getting the errors back on the form when attempting to break a validation rule.

Comment: I called my modelAttribute intface as a test thinking it didn't like when it was called interface, no luck.

Comment: Also, i can prevent the error if i add this code to the controller after the hasErrors() line : 
        model.addAttribute("intface", intface);
but what it does is redirect to the page with no errors on the form.  I am lost

Comment: it literally acts as if the @Valid mechanism was nullifying my intface object before internally passing it back to the view to display the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i FINALLY figured this out.  For whatever the crap reason, i had to change the signature of my controller's saveInterface method to this :

```
public String saveInterface(@Valid @ModelAttribute("intface") Interface intface, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

I have NO IDEA why only THIS entity complains about this when the CRUD operations of all my entity types are built the exact same way but there you go!

Hope this can help someone eventually!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are heading to the form page and it's looking for a pre-instantiated model that aIt's not available. What you have to do is to add the `Interface` object as an attribute of the model:

```
model.addAttribute("intface", new Interface());
```

Remember to add it to the `@RequestMapping` annoted method that takes you to the form page, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayNewInterfaceLogin(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("intface", new Interface()); 
    return "newInterface"; 
}
```

Comment: I did do that but this gets rid of any errors that would normally display in the form error fields, it makes the page act as it's the first time i open it and i haven't entered any data and this is not the behaviour i want.  I will add some working code to my original post for another entity that works just fine.  Spring is capable of somehow internally self-returning this invalid object and display the associated errors that were thrown during validation and for some reason with this one entity that is not happening.

Comment: Any other ideas?